# How magento works phtml/xml?

Tags: xml, magento, php

I'm starting in magento and want to know how some things work.

E.g. sometimes, when searching for a , i find some code in magento like this:

```
  <? php echo $ this-> getChildChildHtml ('container2','', true, true)?>
```

I managed to identify that this code above shows exactly the  that I want to work, but I know that this line only draws the , like to know the path to get to the  and power to change it, knowing that this expedite my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside magento urls you have a path like: module / controller / action. Almost every module has a layout xml file in the base/default theme. The nodes from layout are composed of

`module's frontend name (from module etc/config.xml file) "_" controller "_" action`

so a node from checkout.xml would be like `"checkout_cart_index"`. Inside these nodes from layout xml you have references to parts of the template `<reference name="content">` this is a big block from page.xml defined as shown from one of the page phtmls (1column, 2columns-left, 2columns-right, 3columns, print ...):

`<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>`
and from the phtml:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>`

Now going back to checkout.xml file you can see the child blocks for that reference (keep in mind this is also a block), example:

`<block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">...</block>`

To see a list of methods you should look at the class the block is instantiating, for example if you see in the xml a block that has `type="checkout/cart"` that means you should look for the etc/config.xml that has:

`<blocks>
            <checkout>
                <class>Mage_Checkout_Block</class>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>`

this is actually from the Mage_Checkout module so checkout/cart translates to `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart`

Most blocks in Magento extend `Mage_Core_Block_Template` which has a couple of interesting methods such as setTemplate and _toHtml.

So for `$this->getChildChildHtml('container2','', true, true)` you would have to look inside the layout xml file where your block is defined, there you should see it's children and also the container2 child.
I found a container2 inside catalog.xml

`<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>`

The 'as' value is used instead of the name for future reference of the block. This is the class of this block `Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade`